# Signal 15 not able to kill process

Tags: unix, process

I am trying to kill a Unix process gracefully (Signal 15), but the process is not getting killed. I know that process might be busy somewhere and so signal 15 is not able to kill the process.

My question how can I know here the process is busy? I am mean at which point the process stucked.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try this: it's designed for stopping a USB, but could be of some use: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3109/how-do-i-find-out-which-processes-are-preventing-unmounting-of-a-device

Comment: It's hard to know where to start without knowing more about your program.  What system resources does it use, e.g. files, network, CPU, other devices?  You can use `lsof`, `netstat -anp`, `strace` (on Linux), and other tools to diagnose specific areas.  Some of the most common reasons for a program not terminating on SIGTERM are (a) process in kernel mode during a system call; (b) process is ignoring SIGTERM, e.g. programmed to do so; (c) another process tracing it, e.g. a debugger.